# Error "unhashable type "list"

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and use dataquest to learn the basics. In parallel, i use jupiter QT console to check my code apart from the dataquest stuff.

I have written a little piece of code to extract all the genders out of the data and to append them to a new list. Because i want a list of unique values, i would apply a set function but that's where it goes wrong.

This is my code

```
import csv
f = open("legislators.csv","r")
g = csv.reader(f)
leglist = list(g)
leglist_=leglist[1:]
gender = []
for x in leglist_:
    gender.append(x[3])
gender = set(gender)

This returns an error
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-356f2359660b> in <module>()
----> 1 gender = set(gender)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is weird because when i use the same piece of code in the interpreter on the dataquest website, it returns the unique set of gender values
When i use jupiter QTconsole, it returns the error

What did i do wrong and how is it possible there is a difference?

Kind regards,

Comment: Print out the value of `gender`. It is a list which itself contains lists. You cannot put lists into a set. Didn't you get a bunch of duplicate suggestions when creating this question?

Answer (score -1):

Only immutable objects are hashable in Python. Sets require their items to be hashable. List in not hashable.
You can do smth like this:

```
gender = set()
for x in leglist_:
    if x[3] not in gender: 
        gender.add(x[3])
```

Comment: `x[3]` *is* mutable.

Comment: Immutability is not required. An object that defines `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` can be both mutable and hashable. All that matters is that the return value of `__hash__()` is the same throughout the object's lifetime.